# Login UI in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Hello i have an application in kivy which has username and password

when user enter admin admin it goes to python function and say granted now the problem is

whenever it goes to function and execute the function it would return 1 how do i compare that 1 in kivy file as i am not aware of this and searched a lot no luck

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import time
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
kivy.require('1.10.1')

class Admin(GridLayout,Screen):

    def valid(self,u,p):
        if "admin" == "admin" and "admin" == "admin":
            print('Access Granted !')

        else:
            print('Invalid User')


class UserPage(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv_file = Builder.load_file('Admin.kv')


class AdminApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv_file

r=AdminApp()
r.run()
```

---

```
ScreenManagement:
    Admin:
    UserPage:

<CustLabel@Label>:
    font_size:20

<Custbutton@Button>:
    font_size:20

<MyPopup@Popup>:
    auto_dismiss: False
    Button:
        text: 'Close me!'
        on_release: root.dismiss()

<Admin>:
    name: "Admin"
    id:check
    d_username:entry_username
    d_password:entry_password
    rows:5
    spacing:10

    BoxLayout:
        CustLabel:
            text:'Enter UserName'
        TextInput:
            id:entry_username
            multiline:False
            cursor_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
            hint_text: 'Username'
            padding_x: [50,50]



    BoxLayout:
        CustLabel:
            text:'Enter Password'
        TextInput:
            id:entry_password
            hint_text: 'Password'
            padding_x: [50,50]
            password: True
            multiline:False

    BoxLayout:
        Custbutton:
            text:'Go'
            on_press:check.valid(entry_username.text,entry_password.text)
            # i want to exectute on_release: app.root.current = "userpage" when its true ?????????????


<UserPage>:
    name: "userpage"
    Button:
        text: "back"
        on_release: app.root.current = "Admin"
```

Comment: What "1" do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The callback does not return anything, in general the properties are used to share states, in this case a `BooleanProperty` must be created that indicates if it is authenticated or not.

***.py**

```
class Admin(GridLayout,Screen):
    isAuthenticated =BooleanProperty(False)

    def valid(self,u,p):
        if "admin" == "admin" and "admin" == "admin":
            print('Access Granted !')
            self.isAuthenticated = True
        else:
            print('Invalid User')
```

***.kv**

```
Custbutton:
    text:'Go'
    on_press: check.valid(entry_username.text,entry_password.text)
    on_release: if root.isAuthenticated: app.root.current = "userpage"
```

Although it is not advisable to use on_release to make the Screen change because in general the authentication takes some time so it is better to listen to the change of state:

***.kv**

```
<Admin>:
    name: "Admin"
    id:check
    d_username:entry_username
    d_password:entry_password

    on_isAuthenticated: if root.isAuthenticated: app.root.current = "userpage"
    rows:5
    spacing:10

    BoxLayout:
        CustLabel:
            text:'Enter UserName'
        TextInput:
            id:entry_username
            multiline:False
            cursor_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
            hint_text: 'Username'
            padding_x: [50,50]

    BoxLayout:
        CustLabel:
            text:'Enter Password'
        TextInput:
            id:entry_password
            hint_text: 'Password'
            padding_x: [50,50]
            password: True
            multiline:False

    BoxLayout:
        Custbutton:
            text:'Go'
            on_press: check.valid(entry_username.text,entry_password.text)
```